# Adobe Flash Media Server with AWS activation issue

Tags: flash, amazon-web-services, streaming, adobe, video-streaming

I purchased EC2 AMI for Flash Media Server. Unfortunately I am unable to find any AMI Ids listed on Adobe WebSite with the the [list of AMIs](http://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/kb/flash-media-server-amazon-machine.html#id_735)

I am confused about adding AMI to this. Anybody can help?

[image]

Comment: Are you in the correct region for the purchased AMI? Looks like you need to select EU-West (Ireland) to use that AMI.

Comment: Mine is listed as N.Virginia on EC2 console. I suspect if there are AMIs located for N.Virginia in the list. Changing the location on EC2 console at top right corner will help on this?

Comment: There are several options listed, however in order to find an AMI you need to make sure you're in the correct region for that AMI otherwise you will not be able to find it in a search. I've listed a couple links in my answer below.

Comment: Yes, you need to change your region in the top right hand corner as well as pick the appropriate AMI for the region listed in Adobe's documentation. For N. Virginia it would be `ami-766cce1f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This AMI can only be launched in the EU West region as stated in Adobe's documentation. If you follow [this link](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=eu-west-1#launchAmi=ami-01b5b075&source=thecloudmarket.com), it will begin the process of launching this instance for you.

If you want this in the N. Virginia region, follow [this link](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-1#launchAmi=ami-766cce1f&source=thecloudmarket.com)

[image: This is the screen you should be taken to once you follow the link]

Comment: I have a quick question. Is Adobe Media Server and Flash Media Server is same?

Comment: Looks to me to be the same thing, just renamed for version 5 however I don't have any experience working with it.

Comment: I tried to launch FlashMediaServer with N.Virginia region and I got following error `Unable to launch image ami-07ed6f6e as the product code 8CE147DA is not supported for the specified region, instance type and operating system combination`

Comment: Make sure you are launching instances in the correct configuration. This AMI only supports large instances and up. Also according to [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=363793) Adobe Media Server and Flash Media Server are the same thing. Adobe recommends using version 5.

Comment: Thanks for the great help. the large instance solved the problem. Will ping you if I need help further. Thank you so much once again.